# Adding a string to the end of a line only if the string does not already exist using sed

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to add a string called "SPEC1" to the end of a line which starts with BEGIN, but only if that string doesn't already exist. Some of the matched lines may or may not already have the string.

My example file looks like this:

```
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 SPEC1
some_other_line1
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 value4
some_other_line2
BEGIN value1 value2
```

And the result should look like this:

```
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 SPEC1
some_other_line1
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 value4 SPEC1
some_other_line2
BEGIN value1 value2 SPEC1
```

I am using **sed** to try and achieve this. My current sed solution is like this:

```
sed '/BEGIN/ {
s/ \+SPEC1//g
s|\(.*\)|\1 SPEC1|
}' file
```

Explanation of above:

1. Search for lines that start with "BEGIN"
2. Look for existing string "SPEC1" (may also have one or more spaces in front) and delete it globally to clean up the file
3. Capture the whole matched line (sed BRE style) and append line with "SPEC1"

Is there a better way to achieve this either with sed, awk, perl or bash?

Thanks.

Comment: With `sed`, you cannot do much better since there is no support for lazy quantifiers. Note that `s|\(.*\)|\1 SPEC1|` looks better as `'s|.*|& SPEC1|'` or even `'s|$| SPEC1|'`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the &.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '$1=="BEGIN" && $NF!="SPEC1"{ $(NF+1)="SPEC1" }1' file
```

- `$1` - the 1st field of the current record
- `$NF` - the number of fields in the current input record(points to the last field)
- `$(NF+1)` - generates value for the next field after the last

The output:

```
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 SPEC1
some_other_line1
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 value4 SPEC1
some_other_line2
BEGIN value1 value2 SPEC1
```

Comment: This is the right approach. Clear simple, robust, efficient, portable....

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^BEGIN/&& !/SPEC1$/{$0=$0 FS "SPEC1"}1' inputfile
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 SPEC1
some_other_line1
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 value4 SPEC1
some_other_line2
BEGIN value1 value2 SPEC1
```

If you wish to have `SPEC1` as variable:

```
awk -v string="SPEC1"$"" '/^BEGIN/&&  $0 !~ string{$0=$0 FS string}1' input
```

Comment: That 2nd script doesn't append `$` to the end of `string` and if it did it'd still be present when you add it. It'd also falsely match `FOOSPEC1`, just do a string comparison on $NF (or add anchors to both sides if you feel a burning desire to use a regexp).

Answer (score 1):

Improving the `sed` version mentioned in OP

```
$ sed '/BEGIN/{/ SPEC1/! s/$/ SPEC1/}' ip.txt
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 SPEC1
some_other_line1
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 value4 SPEC1
some_other_line2
BEGIN value1 value2 SPEC1
```

- `/BEGIN/` if line contains `BEGIN` (add start of line qualifier if needed)

  - `/ SPEC1/!` if line doesn't contain `SPEC1` (add end of line qualifier if needed)
  - `s/$/ SPEC1/` add `SPEC1` to end of line

Comment: thanks @sundeep, for remind. i delete my answer because seems does not display well in webpage.

Comment: @yudongshen select the code and click the `{}` editing button or use `ctrl+k` short-cut..

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation @Sundeep. I like the / SPEC1/! negation bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -r '/^BEGIN/s/( SPEC1)?$/ SPEC1/' data
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 SPEC1
some_other_line1
BEGIN value1 value2 value3 value4 SPEC1
some_other_line2
BEGIN value1 value2 SPEC1
```